# opengl transparent mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm rendering a cube, with pure white material, and a grid as a reference floor, using GLSL. For some reason sometimes ( about 1 in 10 times ) the cube is rendered around 50% transparency. I initially thought it to be a Depth buffer issue ( disabled depth buffer, for example ), but i can't find anything about it. There's only one place in the code that touches the depth buffer, and it's initializing it.
I've even forced the GLSL shader to have a fixed value of 1 for Alpha, but still no-go.

Here are some screenshots i took to illustrate the problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here's the shader code:

Lighting.vs

```
#version 300 es

in vec3 VertexPosition;
uniform mat4 MVP;
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec2 TexCoord0;

void main()
    {
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
    TexCoord0 = TexCoord;
    }
```

Lighting.fs

```
#version 300 es

precision lowp float;
in vec2 TexCoord0;
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform sampler2D TextureSampler;

uniform struct
    {
    bool Textured;
    bool Litable;
    }Flags;

uniform struct
    {
    vec4 Diffuse;
    }Material;

uniform struct
    {
    vec3 Color;
    float Intensity;
    }AmbientLight;

vec4 ApplyTexturing ( vec4 Input )
    {
    Input *= texture(TextureSampler, TexCoord0);
    return Input;
    }

vec4 ApplyLighting ( vec4 Input )
    {
    Input *= vec4(AmbientLight.Color * AmbientLight.Intensity, 1.0f );
    return Input;
    }

void main()
    {
    vec4 TempFragColor = vec4 ( Material.Diffuse.xyz, 1.0f );
    if ( Flags.Textured )
    TempFragColor = ApplyTexturing( TempFragColor );

    if ( Flags.Litable )
    TempFragColor = ApplyLighting ( TempFragColor );

    FragColor = vec4(TempFragColor.xyz, 1.0f);
    }
```

This is the only place in the code that touches the depth buffer:

```
glEnable ( GL_CULL_FACE );
glCullFace ( GL_BACK );
glFrontFace ( GL_CCW );
glEnable ( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glDepthMask ( GL_TRUE );
glDepthFunc ( GL_LEQUAL );
glDepthRange ( 1, 100 );
```

Now, as i write this, i'm wondering if i should use glClearDepth() to set a default value? I assumed the driver would use a decent default value, so i didn't specify.

EDIT: Ok, so i changed the code to use glClearDepth. No change. This definitely looks like a transparency issue, though. Take a look at this shot, with a textured cube.

[image]

```
bool CGLWindow::StartFrame ( void )
{
    glfwMakeContextCurrent ( MyGLFWWindow );
    glfwPollEvents();
    glEnable ( GL_CULL_FACE );
    glCullFace ( GL_BACK );
    glFrontFace ( GL_CCW );
    glEnable ( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glDepthMask ( GL_TRUE );
    glDepthFunc ( GL_LEQUAL );
    glDepthRange ( 1, 100 );
    glClearColor ( 0, 0, 0, 1.0f );
    glClearDepth ( 1.0f );

    Clear();
    glfwGetCursorPos ( MyGLFWWindow, & ( MouseCursor.CursorPos.X ), & ( MouseCursor.CursorPos.Y ) );
    return glfwWindowShouldClose ( MyGLFWWindow );
}

bool CGLWindow::Clear ( void )
{
    glViewport ( 0, 0, Size.X, Size.Y );
    glScissor ( 0, 0, Size.X, Size.Y );
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    return glCheckError();
}
```

EDIT:
Ok, some breakthrough.
I switched to a simple fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision lowp float;

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec4 Color;

void main()
    {
    FragColor.r = FragColor.g = FragColor.b = FragColor.a = 1.0f;
    }
```

This isn't deterministic, but like i said, every once in a while, i'd get a transparent cube. And now, it stopped doing it. Now all is ok.

So, i started cutting down my fragment shader. This is the minimum i got, with it failing with a transparent cube.

```
#version 300 es

precision lowp float;
in vec2 TexCoord0;
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform sampler2D TextureSampler;

uniform struct
    {
    vec4 Diffuse;
    }Material;

void main()
    {
    vec4 TempFragColor = vec4 ( Material.Diffuse.xyz, 1.0f );

    FragColor = vec4(TempFragColor.xyz, 1.0f);
    }
```

What can i possibly be doing wrong here?
It definitely seems to be the shader.

Comment: The default value in the depth buffer is 1. The [reference](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClearDepth.xhtml) is online, there's no need to guess or assume. When you say that nothing else touches the depth buffer, do you mean that you don't clear it?

Comment: I clear it. I've edited the post to include the clear function.

Comment: @genpfault I had C++ in the title because it could be an error on my C++ code. Only later ( hence the edits ) did i find out not to be the case. No need to edit and downvote something because of that.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but generally you want to avoid `conditional statements` like **If** in OpenGL shaders due to their performance hit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your setup will not give you a functional depth buffer. The problem is with this call:

```
glDepthRange ( 1, 100 );
```

The depth buffer has a range of 0.0 to 1.0. These values determine the mapping from NDC (Normalized Device Coordinates) to the range of the depth buffer. The default values correspond to:

```
glDepthRange(0.0, 1.0);
```

which means that the depth range in NDC (which is from -1.0 to 1.0) is mapped to the whole available depth buffer range. `glDepthRange()` can only **reduce** the range of depth values that the NDC range is mapped to. You can't extend the range of the depth buffer beyond its default full range.

Therefore, both arguments to `glDepthRange()` need to be between 0.0 and 1.0. It is not an error to specify values outside this range. The values are clamped, as defined in the spec:

> The parameters n and f are clamped to the range [0,1], as are all arguments of type clampd or clampf.

With the second parameter `100` clamped, your call is equivalent to:

```
glDepthRange(1.0, 1.0);
```

This means that everything is mapped to depth value 1.0, which is pretty much like having no depth buffer at all.

Unless you have a very good reason for different values, you rarely need to call `glDepthRange()` at all. The defaults are fine for the most common use cases.

Based on the values you used, you might have expected them to be the depth range in world/eye coordinates. But that range is defined by the near and far parameters of the projection transformation, which takes care of mapping the [near, far] range to the [-1, 1] NDC range. What we're looking at here with the `glDepthRange()` parameters happens later in the pipeline.

Comment: How to say this... Marry me. I can't believe i missed that one! You're a genius! Thank you so much for solving this :) ( Can i only upvote once??? dammit )